# Error deleting large allocations C++

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to delete memory allocation using a function.. The code is as follow...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int NOS, *NO, *SQR;

int Square()
{
    SQR = new int [NOS];
    if (!SQR)
    {
        cout<<"Mem Error SQR \n";
        exit(0);
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < NOS; i++ )
    {
        SQR[i] = NO[i]*NO[i];
    }
}

void ERASE_MEM()
{
    if (SQR)    delete [] SQR;
    cout<<"Deleted 1\n";
    if (NO != NULL)     delete [] NO;
    cout<<"Deleted 2\n";
}

int main ()
{
    cout<<"Enter No : ";
    cin >> NOS;
    NO = new int [NOS];
    if (!NO)    
    {
        cout<<"Mem Error NO \n";
        exit(0);
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < NOS; i++ )
    {
        NO[i] = 1+i;
    }
    Square();
    delete  NO;
    ERASE_MEM();
}
```

If the number is less than 15, the program works fine but if the NOS is greater than 15, I get the following error:

*** glibc detected**  ./MEM: double free or corruption (top): 0x097fa008 **

I am doing this in order to create one function for all the memory de-allocations, that I can call while allocating memory. If allocation fails, this function will de-allocate all previous allocations.

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question, but don't check the result of `new` for null. It will normally throw if there's an error allocating memory.

Comment: You also don't have to check for a null pointer before deleting, as delete is required to handle null pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You are deleting `NO` twice, once in `main` and once inside `ERASE_MEM`. Also, the syntax of `delete` used in `main` is wrong, since its an array you should use `delete[]` (or better remove the statement). BTW, one more thing to note is that when `new` fails it doesn't return a NULL pointer instead it throws `std::bad_alloc` exception. So there is no point validating the memory location retunred from `new`. Also, do not use all capital letters for a function name, the general coding practice is to use the all caps name for macros only. It is also not necessary to check for NULL pointer before calling `delete[]`. Standard guarantees that deleting a NULL pointer will not do anything.

Comment: And the delete in `main` should be `delete [] NO`.

Answer (score 2):

You delete NO (incorrectly) in the main code and then again (correctly) in ERASE_MEM

edit: calling delete doesn't set pointer to null, it can't do this since the call only gets the value of the pointer, not the pointer itself.
This is a little clearer with the 'C' version `free(pData)` can't change pData - only what pData points to.  A common 'C' idiom is to define your own `Free(void **ptr)` which you call with `Free(&pData)` which can then set pData to NULL.
Also note that it's perfectly safe to call free / delete with a null pointer, the function does the check for you.

Don't feel too bad `delete` and `delete []` are a nasty corner of C++, they are function calls that look like statements, and the [] syntax to delete and array is even worse. The only good part is that with smart pointers and modern C++ you never have to use them

Comment: In the function I first check if NO is NULL or NOT. My guess is if I have deleted NO, it will become NULL, so the if statement will be false and the program terminates without error. This scheme work well if NOS < 16, otherwise I get error message.

Comment: I want to delete all the previous memory allocation before exiting the program if a memory allocation fails. I don't want to write too many delete statements. Something like, just call a function which takes care of all the deallocations.

Comment: @DKTR: You probably don't need to worry about deleting your allocations before exiting. But if you do, initialize your pointers to null and then call `ERASE_MEM()` before each `exit()` call.

Comment: @DKTR: If you trying this code for learning purpose then its fine to do this manual memory management, otherwise take a look at the smart pointer concept to do this automatically.